# Using Android back button after delete an item with SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, back-button

I have a problem when using the back-button in my app (API 17). There are two activities in my project:
The main activity with a ListView reading items from a xml-file.

A second activity which is reading the same xml-file but using only the items which has been checked and saved by the main activity.

If I remove an item from the ListView in the second activity and use the app's menu to go back to the main-activity after saving the xml-file when swiping, this item is now unchecked. It's because the xml-file has been altered after swiping and the value for "isDone" was set from true to false.

So far so good!

But if I go back using the Android back-button the deleted item has is still checked.
What went wrong?
I guess it has something to do with the lifecycle of the activities. But I can not figure it out. Do I have to read the altered and saved xml-file in onResume again? I assumed it will be read again when the main-activity starts after using the back-button from the second activity.

And what I really do not understand is this:
When I debug the code I can see that the xml-file was not altered after swipping the item in the second activity and save the changed isDone value to the xml. This seems a little bit strange to me.

Any help would be fine!

Main-Activity:

```
    package com.wbapps.wbshoppinglist;

/**
 * Created by Andreas on 9/4/2017.
 */

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /*wb, 19Sep,2017: not yet
    public static final int REQUEST_ID = 1;
     */
    ImageButton imgbtnAddItem;
    Button btn_create_shopping_list;
    EditText input;

    //object for the ListView from activity_main.xml
    ListView list_view;

    List<Task> tasks;
    TodoListAdapter adapter;
    XmlParser parser;
    File file;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tasks.xml");
        parser = new XmlParser();
        tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();

        //file.delete();
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                tasks = parser.read(file);
                if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
                    file.delete();
                    file.createNewFile();
                }else {sortList();}
            } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        //Initialize the variables
        imgbtnAddItem = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_task_button);
        btn_create_shopping_list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_shopping_list);
        /* findViewById(R.id.list_view).requestFocus(); */
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_task);
        /* id list_view identifies the listview from the activity_main.xmll */
        list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        registerForContextMenu(list_view);

        //tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        adapter = new TodoListAdapter(tasks, this);
        list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        //To swipe away an litem from the list
        SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
                new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                        list_view,
                        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    tasks.remove(position);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        });
        list_view.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

        //set the onClickListener for the button
        imgbtnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (input.getText().length() > 0) {
                    /* wb, 16Sep2017: look if the new item is already in the list */
                    Boolean itemfound = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i<tasks.size(); i++){
                        if (tasks.get(i).getTaskContent().equalsIgnoreCase(input.getText().toString())){
                            itemfound = true;
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("This item is already in the list!");
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (itemfound == false){
                        tasks.add(new Task(input.getText().toString(), false));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        sortList();
                        input.setText("");
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        btn_create_shopping_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShoppingListActivity.class));
                Boolean selected = false;
                Task taskTmp;
                for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
                    taskTmp = tasks.get(i);
                    if (taskTmp.isDone()) {
                        selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (selected) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShoppingListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    /* startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID); */
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("No items for shopping list selected!");
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //wb, Sep 13, 2017:
        //before doing something else - like calling a new activity - write the altered list to
        //the data sourc file tasks.xml file
        try {
            parser.write(tasks, file);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /* Do I have to do the same here like in onCreate? It does not work yet!*/
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                tasks = parser.read(file);
                if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
                    file.delete();
                    file.createNewFile();
                }else {sortList();}
            } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_clear_all:
                clearDonetasks();
                this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case R.id.action_delete_done_tasks:
                deleteDonetasks();
                this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case R.id.action_delete_all:
                this.tasks.clear();
                this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //wb, 15 Sep, 2017: take out the hook from checkbox
    public void clearDonetasks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            if (tasks.get(i).isDone()) {
                tasks.get(i).setIsDone(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteDonetasks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            if (tasks.get(i).isDone()) {
                tasks.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int position = (int) info.id;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.context_delete:
                this.tasks.remove(position);
                this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            case R.id.context_edit:
                createEditDialog(tasks.get(position));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void createEditDialog(final Task task) {

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.edit_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText inputText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_dialog_input);
        inputText.setText(task.getTaskContent());
        final TextView dialogMessage = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_dialog_message);

        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                task.setTaskContent(inputText.getText().toString());
                                sortList();
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        final AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    /* wb, 18Sep2017: sort the tasks list */
    public void sortList() {
        Collections.sort(tasks, new Comparator<Task>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Task content1, Task content2) {
                /* return o1.getTaskContent().compareTo(o2.getTaskContent()); */
                /* ignore case sentsitivity */
                return content1.getTaskContent().compareToIgnoreCase(content2.getTaskContent());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Second Activity:

```
    package com.wbapps.wbshoppinglist;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Created by Andreas on 9/4/2017.
 */

public class ShoppingListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /*wb, 19Sep2017: Not yet
    public static final String RETVAL_KEY = "RETURN STRING";
    */
    ListView shopping_list_view;
    List<Task> tasks, shoppingTasks;
    TodoListAdapter adapter;
    XmlParser parser;
    File file;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shoppinglist);

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tasks.xml");
        parser = new XmlParser();
        tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        shoppingTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                tasks = parser.read(file);
                if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No Items in Shopping List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //file.delete();
                    //file.createNewFile();
                } else {
                    /*
                    Collections.sort(tasks, new Comparator<Task>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
                            return o1.getTaskContent().compareTo(o2.getTaskContent());
                        }
                    });
                    */
                    addDonelistitems();
                }
            } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Task File not existing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        //create an instance for the view of the lauout
        shopping_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shoppingListView);
        registerForContextMenu(shopping_list_view);

        adapter = new TodoListAdapter(shoppingTasks, this);
        shopping_list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
                new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                        shopping_list_view,
                        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    //wb, 15Sep: With swipe an item uncheck the checkbox for this item in the file for the shopping items
                                    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
                                        if (tasks.get(i).getTaskContent() == shoppingTasks.get(position).getTaskContent()) {
                                            tasks.get(i).setIsDone(false);
                                            try {
                                                parser.write(tasks, file);
                                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    shoppingTasks.remove(position);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        });
        shopping_list_view.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
       }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            /* I jaust added a toas there to see if I will reach here */
            Toast.makeText(this, "we are in onBackPressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        public void addDonelistitems() {

            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
                if (tasks.get(i).isDone() == true) {
                    shoppingTasks.add(tasks.get(i));
                }
            }
        }


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int position = (int) info.id;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.context_delete:
                this.tasks.remove(position);
                this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            case R.id.context_edit:
                createEditDialog(tasks.get(position));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void createEditDialog(final Task task) {

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ShoppingListActivity.this);
        View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.edit_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShoppingListActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText inputText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_dialog_input);
        inputText.setText(task.getTaskContent());
        final TextView dialogMessage = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_dialog_message);

        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Save",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                task.setTaskContent(inputText.getText().toString());
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        final AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: disable back button otherwise you need to implement onactivityresult for android back button and in that notify adapter first.

Comment: have you tried super.onBackPressed() instead of finish() ;

Comment: Sorry Sai, but I do not understand how to handle this super.onBackPressed. Just instead of finish(). in my methos "public void onBackPressed()"? What should be the result of that? And how eill it help to get the right value for the isDone value in the xml-file?

Answer (score 0):

after trying a little bit around today it seems I solved my problem with the back-button. It seems to be I forgot to set the adapter to the list_view in onResume when comming back from the second activity. After changing the code to this

```
    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            /* Do I have to do the same here like in onCreate? It does not work yet!*/
            Toast.makeText(this, "onResume is reached!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (file.exists()) {
                try {
                    tasks = parser.read(file);
                    if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
                        file.delete();
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }else {

 ==>>new code here      adapter = new TodoListAdapter(tasks, this);
 ==>>new code here      list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

                        sortList();}
                } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
```

everything worked fine. 
I guess without the new code the adapter put the values from the old xml-file to the list_view.

Guess I have to learn a lot of more with android!

Many thanks to all who are trying to help me!

Have a nice day wherever you are

Andreas